# How to add azure function's javascript / c# code into terraform scripts?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform

I am working in a project that will be deployed at my client's Microsoft Azure. Thus I am currently testing *terraform* to assist me when the time comes. 
create a azure function with terraform that will trigger on blob storage input data

My question is about how to add  the azure functions's javascript/c# code into the terraform script so it will be automatically deployed ?

I checked the terraform docs, but it wasn't of much help:
https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/function_app.html

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am checking the same and looks like it can be done using ZIP package. I am going to try it out soon. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842499/deploy-azure-function-using-terraform

Answer (score 0):

Terraform doesn't handle pushing code to Azure resources, that's usually done in a following step in the pipeline (e.g. 1- execute terraform 2- deploy code).

However, the Azure Function App does have the ability to connect directly to your repo, and the Terraform `azurerm_function_app` module exposes the `source_control` property.

[Terraform's azurerm_function_app documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment)

So with Terraform you can configure the function app to pull the code directly from the repo when a change is detected.

[Microsoft's Azure Function Continuous Deployment documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-continuous-deployment)

Answer (score 0):

This is a quite old post but I have managed to add code to a function, so for the benefit of others, add the following to the azurerm_function_app_function

```
file {
   name    = "some name"
   content = file("xxx.js") # or file content
}
```