# Deploy azure function using terraform

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have an example how to deploy azure function using terraform. But, unfortunately, it deploys only zip package. Is there are any other way to do it? How can I deploy multiple packages into one function? How can I configure proxy using terraform?

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "azure_function_scenario1_hop2" {
      name                      = "scenario1-hop2-azure-function"
      location                  = "${var.location}"
      resource_group_name       = "${var.resource_group_name}"
      app_service_plan_id       = "${var.app_service_plan_id}"
      storage_connection_string = "${var.storage_connection_string}"

      app_settings {
        APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY = "${var.instrumentation_key}"
        HASH                           = "${base64sha256(file("./../bin/scenario1_hop2_node.zip"))}"
        WEBSITE_USE_ZIP                = "https://github.com/lmolotii/azure-functions-playgroud/raw/master/scenario1_hop2_node.zip"
      }
    }
```

Comment: Not familiar with Terraform, but generally, you should never be trying to deploy individual functions. Instead, you should be deploying the **function app** as a unit (and that can include proxies). In the end, it's just a bunch of files.

Comment: Totally agree, but I don't know even if it is feasible using terraform.

Comment: I see you are using `WEBSITE_USE_ZIP`, which is great. You just need to make sure that your zip contains all the functions (and proxies) that you care about. There is no need to ever deploy more than one package if your package contains the entire Function App content.

Comment: Unfortunately, this package will be read-only. But the main pain here, I didn't find any way to specify a path to the local file, and each time I need to upload my content to the public git repository...

Comment: Can you clarify what issue you're having when you say the package is read-only? For the zip, you should not store it in a git repo, which is a very bad fit for binaries. Instead, just upload it to a storage blob.

Comment: I cannot modify the source code in the console, and also it doesn't allow me to configure it. (set get, post, put methods).

Comment: you either do client development or portal development. You can't mix the two models. So if deploying from zip, it's by design that the app is read-only in the portal

Comment: Is there any another way to deploy function not using zip package using terraform?

Comment: Do you know how I could invoke function without a usage of the function key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of version 3.0 of the `azurerm` provider, you can deploy Functions using Terraform.  You just need the `azurerm_function_app_function` resource as is documented here:  https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/function_app_function